# Google Gmail on Android 12 now only share e-mail attachments with WhatsApp

Tags: gmail, attachments, whatsapp-messenger

A short while ago, on my Motorola cell phone, when I opened up an e-mail attachment I could select which app I would use to share the file/photo with.

I was used to share through **WhatsApp**, but accidentally I checked an option to
always share via WhatsApp. Now I cannot revert it back, so that I can choose
another app to do the sharing with.

By chance, someone ever found out a way to restore the choice of apps when
sharing a e-mail attachment through Google Gmail on Android 12 ?

I've searched through Google Gmail settings, but to no avail thus far.

Comment: Find the 'Default Apps' section of Settings>Apps (it may occur as a menu selection). Select Whatsapp and click button 'Clear Defaults' or similar in your device. The option to set another app in its place should occur the next time the operation is needed.

Comment: Right on spot, @wbogacz. Many thanks!

Comment: @wbogacz looks like your suggestion solves the OP's problem. Would you like to convert it to a proper answer?